# How to link ABPerson in ABAdressbook

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook

How to link `ABPerson` in `ABAdressbook`, so that `ABPerson's` linkedPerson will show the linked status?

I have tried to look up in Apple's documentation but didn't find anything to create the linked person.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? Struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I have submitted a technical support to apple and they replied that no public API is available for this.

Comment: Urgh :( 
That's really gross.
Do you want to submit a self-answer to your question stating this, then?

Comment: What do you mean gross? Does it provide information or it just make your life gross? You shouldn't care because you are not looking for answers like me.

Comment: It is gross that Apple do not have a public API for a common user interaction. I am/was looking for answers, like you. You have found an answer: There is no public API. In the spirit of StackOverflow's Question and Answer, self-answered questions are encouraged. Adding that answer would benefit the community, instead of having to read these comments.

Comment: OK got you. I misinterpreted your language. I thought that you don't like self answering comment...

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. I have submitted a technical support to apple and they replied that no public API is available for this. Thumb down for apple on this.